# Animating SVG elements in jQuery + namespaced attribute issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, jquery-animate, jquery-svg

I'm trying to do some basic animations on shapes in an SVG in jQuery, loaded with jQuery SVG.

### Problem 1:

Any time I try to animate a standard element, my console throws up an error:

Code:

```
// Load the map - this works fine!
var svgNode = $(divSelector).svg('get');
svgNode.clear();
svgNode.load(mapPath, {
    addTo: false,
    changeSize: true,
    onLoad: resizeSvg  // This is a function elsewhere that resizes the SVG to fill or fit within the container, using a viewbox.
});

// Try to animate all path objects
var objSelector = 'path';
// Got to add svgNode.root() to the selector, or jQuery doesn't know where to look.
if( $($(objSelector), svgNode.root()).length > 0 ) {
    $($(objSelector), svgNode.root() ).animate({
        'svgFill': 'lightblue'
    }, 2000);
}
```

This throws up the following error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (jquery.svganim.js:250)

It looks like jQuery takes the animate call, and passes it to jQuery SVG's animation script properly, but it fails. Still not sure why.

### Problem 2:

I want to reference an object by the value of a namespaced attribute, namely inkscape:label. I've had issues with this in the past with CSS, which were solved by adding a `@namespace` tag to the top of the CSS file and referring to the attribute keys by `inkscape|label`, however jQuery SVG seems to be having its own issues finding the objects:

```
var svgNode = $(divSelector).svg('get');
var labelVal = 'foo';
var objSelector = '[inkscape\|label=\"' + labelVal + '\"]';
console.log("Selector String: '" + objSelector + "'");
console.log("Objects matched: " + $($(objSelector), svgNode.root()).length );
```

Despite there being at least one SVG path element that matches `foo`, this is always the output of the console:

```
Selector String: '[inkscape\|label="foo"]'
Objects matched: 0
```

I've tried various ways of writing the selector, including (but not limited to):

```
inkscape:label
inkscape|label
inkscape\\:label
inkscape\\|label
inkscape\\\:label
inkscape\\\|label
```

But nothing seems to work. Some throw up errors, some don't, but still find 0 objects. The same console log messages using just `path` as the selector properly identifies 42 elements in the file.

I can only assume that jQuery SVG is having issues with the namespaced attribute name, but I'm not sure how to make it aware of it in the same way I did in my CSS file.

Any suggestions would be fantastic, and beer would be owed.

Comment: Did you get a solution with this? I'm having the same problem and I don't find any solution :(

Comment: Unfortunately I don't remember if  I did - It was 3 years ago, on a project for a company I no longer work for :(

Answer (score 0):

> **Problem 2:**
>
> I want to reference an object by the value of a namespaced attribute,
>   namely inkscape:label

Try

`"[inkscape\\:label=" + labelVal + "]"`

```js
var labelVal = "abc";
$("[inkscape\\:label=" + labelVal + "]").text("abc");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div inkscape:label="abc"></div>
```

Comment: Yep, tried that already; your example works with just jQuery, but jQuery SVG doesn't seem to want to work with it :(